# MySQL Search for words and its variations

Tags: mysql

My Database tables are InnoDB and I am running MySQL 5.6.

I need to run a query on the database that returns more of a natural language result.

For example if I were to do a search like:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE MATCH (productName) AGAINST ('rose');
```

As expected I get all the products that contain the word rose.

**BUT** I need to be able to use variations of the word rose and get the same result. ex: roses

examples of rose results:

- Cabaret Rose
- Dbl. Madness Rose White
- New Day Rose Stripe

Comment: Can you use `LIKE '%rose%'`?

Comment: LIKE '%rose%' Will give me the same result. but I need to use the search term "roses" and get the results as if i was using "rose" - LIKE '%roses%'will not give me the result I am looking for.

Comment: Are your search terms structured consistently, ie, to they all end in "s"?  Is this just a matter of stripping the e and/or s off the end? Otherwise how are you determining that "roses" should return "rose"?

Comment: No they wont all be structured. I have a Search Tool on my website and It needs to be able to search the database (And it does. Works fine). But people are having a hard time using the search as all my names are singular. Many people are trying to search using the plural "roses, lilies, etc". I am attempting to find out if this type of search exists. I can just strip the last letter of the search term. But if someone actually uses "rose" and I strip the "e" it gives many more results than it is supposed to

Comment: Maybe identify the most problematic search terms, add them to an array, and use the array to filter user input before building your query. Or add some logic that looks for common patterns (like "es" at the end of a search term)